# how to solve transport close on disconnect socket.io?

Tags: javascript, socket.io

server side:

```
socket.on('disconnect', function(userid) {
        users[userid]= socket.id;
        console.log(userid);
        io.emit("user_disconnect",userid);
            console.log('user disconnected');

  });
```

client side:

```
   var io = io("http://localhost:5500");
   io.emit("user_connected",sessionStorage.getItem('userid'));
   io.emit("disconnect",sessionStorage.getItem('userid'));
   io.on("user_connected",function(userid)
   {
    console.log(userid);
   })
   io.on("user_disconnect",function(userid)
   {
    console.log(userid);
   })
```

[image]

I want to update database on disconnection but it showing transport close instead on id.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i just want to update status in database on user disconnect .